# How did vacuum and temperature play in to a baggie sucked in to a water jug?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

I placed a plastic sandwich bag over the spout of a plastic water jug after filling it half full with hot water. Why did the plastic sandwich bag the next morning, appear to be sucked downward toward the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

When you filled the jug the air above the water was about the same temperature as the water. As the water and air cooled, the volume of air decreased (the volume of gases increase with temperature) and this sucked in the bag. Had it not been airtight air would just have leaked in and kept the volume constant.

Answer (score 0):

Two factors contribute: thermal expansion of air and water vapor partial pressure.  When you fill a jug with hot water, the air above the water quickly warms up.  As it slowly cools along with the water, it contracts according to $PV=nRT$.  Warm air above warm water includes quite a lot of water molecules.  As the air cools, that water vapor condenses (look up Clausius-Clapeyron relation).  The liquid water it forms takes up far less space than the vapor.

If you boil water in a jug (probably not a plastic one) you can fill the space above the water with nearly 100% water vapor.  If you then cap the jug and cool it, the water vapor condenses, and atmospheric pressure can crush the jug to a small fraction of its former volume.  There are lots of demonstrations on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsoE4F2Pb20).